# inline editing with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do inline editing in a form with an Angular directive, unfortunately I ran into two issues and I can't get around them, so a second opinion will be very much appreciated.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgecas99/bc65N/

Question 1:
As you can see I added a section that is suppose to listen to key strokes (in this case the esc key) and exit the edit mode, unfortunately it is not working. I tried listening for key 13 which is 'enter' and that worked ok, so I don't understand.

Question 2:
I will like to change the second field to a dropdown when you click to edit it without having to create a new directive, is that even possible? I certainly care about number of lines of code so if this can be achieve with one directive, then that would be my preferred option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for first question, you can see a revised version of your fiddle which incorporate the technique described in 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/saving-contenteditable-content-changes-as-json-with-ajax/ here http://jsfiddle.net/bonamico/cAHz7/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

please note that var myApp = was missing, and so the following declaration did not execute

```
myApp.directive('contenteditable', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        // view -> model
        elm.bind('blur', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
            });
        });

        // model -> view
        ctrl.render = function(value) {
            elm.html(value);
        };

        // load init value from DOM
        ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());

        elm.bind('keydown', function(event) {
            console.log("keydown " + event.which);
            var esc = event.which == 27,
                el = event.target;

            if (esc) {
                    console.log("esc");
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
                    el.blur();
                    event.preventDefault();                        
                }

        });

    }
};
```

});

See also
http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

For the second question, I would suggest that minimizing numer of lines of code is not normally a main concern, while making code modular and maintainable is. So it would be definitely better to create two directives, and possibly a common javascript function for the commonm parts between the two, if any.

Comment: ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html()); in the if (esc) block is not needed because you're triggering blur and are already always doing that in the blur handler